# Facing connection issue with mysql while connecting with R-10060

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to connect R to the MySql server and getting the following error:

> ```
> "Error in .local(drv,....)
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet' , system error :10060"
> ```

Please note that I am facing this issue on the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure you can connect using a basic MySQL client from the machine you are running your R code on first.  That will help you eliminate firewall, hostname, username, password, etc issues.  (Seems likely that is what your problem really is: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?34,49742,239961).

Comment: Hi, thanks for ans, but i am facing this issue on localhost

Comment: Same advice applies. The error message is generic and does not seem to reflect an R specific problem

Comment: If you've a dockerized minimally replicable example, it might be possible to help you further.

Comment: This is code i am using con<- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname ="sakila", host="127.0.0.1",user="root", password ="pass123")